# Xamarin Forms - Custom Renderer Can't Get Native Control (UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I have a class called RecordProvider2. It inherits from ContentView. I want to grab an instance of the native control behind the scenes. I'm not sure what that control is on UWP, but according to this article, it should be FrameworkElement (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers/).

So, I wrote this custom renderer, and by all accounts, I should be able to access the native control with the "Control" property of the renderer. However, in the OnElementChanged event, the Control property is always null. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class RecordProvider2Renderer : ViewRenderer<RecordProvider2, FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<RecordProvider2> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: As mentioned below, the renderer itself just **IS** the native control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `this` to get access to native control instance.

```
 if (e.OldElement == null)
 {
       var nativeCtrl = this;
```

Or, use `this.ContainerElement`.

**EDIT 1** - Note: the above code will give access to the native container of control. Which works pretty well for `ContentView`; as most of the native behaviors such as gestures handling etc. can be assigned to it.

Comment: this is the customer renderer, not the native control.

Comment: which inherits from `Panel`

Comment: Mind blown! Thanks. This has made my understanding of custom renders fall in to place now. The ViewRenderer inherits from the control on the native platform. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Not on all platforms - only on WinRT, and UWP

Comment: Just a note on this one. It's best to override the constructor because handling events on the control may be too late in the OnElementChanged method. Before I changed my code, event handlers were not getting attached.

Answer (score 0):

You need to,

```
SetNativeControl(new Panel())
```

before Control is `NOT-NULL`.

The panel is whatever native control you are rendering.